# Placing a retrieve-marker before the marker it refers to

Tags: xsl-fo

I've got a page-sequence where a list of data appears on the odd pages, and the accompanying drawing appears on the even pages.

```
Page 1: introduction
page 2: drawing that belongs to the data on page 3, with retrieve-marker in the page header.
page 3: data, with marker
```

I can't get the retrieve-marker to work: it is always empty on page 2. The same retrieve-marker works correctly on page 4, so my code isn't broken. 
I've tried `<fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-boundary="document">`, thinking that would expand the scope of the search for markers to my entire document, but that didn't help.

It looks like the retrieve-marker cannot be placed before the marker. Is that correct, or am I overlooking something?

**Edit**: 
I've worked around the issue by creating a block on page 1 that reads the data from page 3 (using following:: to get the data that will be displayed on page 3) and sets a marker.